# Repeating Group header on each page in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have a main report and 1 sub report.In sub report i created a dummy group and checked repeat gh on each page to show headers in every page .
But some times if the summary values came in new page the headers are not showing.(when there is no detail section values and only  summary values).
How to resolve this.

Comment: Keeping Information on page header and page footer is a better alternative rather than 'Repeat group header on each page'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click on Group Header - "Change Group" - "Options" - Check "Repeat group on each page"

Answer (score 37):

- Go to Group Expert
- Click on 'options' button
- Select the 'options' tab
- Check on 'Repeat group header on each page'

Comment: See here for more options: http://www.microassist.com/tips/crystal-reports-prevent-orphaned-group-header

Comment: What if the one I want to show at every page is the Group Footer? Is there  a way? @user2866649

Comment: yes there is a way. Add an identical group below and put you footer there. Crystal will think the outer group still has content and will print the header.

Answer (score 0):

Check you may have checked "New Page After" or "New Page Before" options in summary or header.

Check and let me know the result. Will try to help

Comment: Hi i didn't checked those options.Please help

Comment: Have you checked "New Page After" for the summary section?

Comment: Normally if you check those option then header will be displayed in other page other wise header will follow the group footer. If you can give some  more detail on how you have prepared the report I will try to help.