# How do I keep same title header on different page in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

I want to display same title row in the other page on data. How do I populate that?

Image that has no title
[image: Image that has no title]

Image that has title and it should be repeated on the other page
[image: Image that has title and it should be repeated on the other page]

Viewer in Crystal report
[image: Viewer in Crystal report]

I have applied Repeat Group Header on each page but it keeps showing the upper master table. I only want the header to be applied for Master Details only!
[image: I have applied Repeat Group Header on each page but it keeps showing the upper master table. I only want the header to be applied for Master Details only!]

This is done using Crystal report on ASP.NET MVC. How will I populate the title row on the other page too?

Comment: In which section is the title-row currently located?

Comment: Second picture SL Item Name Quantity, this one!

Comment: No, i mean in which report-section is it placed currently...header, group-header, page-header, ...???

Comment: @MatSnow I have added new image you can see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeating Group header on each page in crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772218/repeating-group-header-on-each-page-in-crystal-reports)

Comment: @MatSnow Please check the fourth image with details!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164233/discussion-between-nabid-and-matsnow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just right click on the group and take group expert, now a new window will come, in that you can see an Options button click on that , now another window will come in this click on Option tab , here you can see an option "Repeat Group Header On Each Page" Check that Option